# Django save post via celery

Tags: python, django, celery

I have a particular use case where i write text for a blog post in admin dashboard. Then i want to generate the embeddings of post.
I am doing this in `admin.py`

```
@admin.register(Post)
class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('title', 'author', 'created_at')
    readonly_fields = ('embeddings_calculated','emebddings_updated_at') 

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        if not obj.meta_title:
            obj.meta_title = obj.title
            obj.meta_description = obj.content[:160]
        super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)

        print("django post id",obj.id)
        post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=obj.id)
        print("django post title",post)
        if not change: # if new post not an edit post
            task_id = perform_task.delay(obj.id)
        
        result = AsyncResult(str(task_id), app=app)
        print("AsyncResultx", result)
        print("AsyncResultx_state", result.state)
```

here is my celery task

```
@shared_task()
def perform_task(post_id):
    print("celery post id",post_id)
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=post_id)
    print("celery post title",post)
```

I am getting this error

```
django.http.response.Http404: No Post matches the given query.
```

Though the print statement such as `django post id` and `django post title` show me correct result. But the issue lies in celery. I cant see `celery post title` in console.

I aslo tried

```
task_id = transaction.on_commit(lambda: perform_task.delay(obj.id))
```

But it did not work as well. Without celery every thing work well, but i want to use celery.

Comment: It is not clear what relevance the celery task has to what you are doing in the admin dashboard (such what, where, or when the task is scheduled), or why the 404 error could be for anything other than the `id` you are attempting to find not existing.  Can you please provide more context.